# MVC 4: My form is posting a list of models - so - where are the model errors going?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a model class (let's call it OrderLineModel) and it implements IValidatableObject.

When I render a list of lines on my form, I loop through "lines" property of the parent model (let's call it Order) and spit out some non-imaginative razor code:

```
 @For Each item In Model.Lines
    Dim currentItem = item
        @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("[" & i & "].Quantities.Tentative", currentItem.Quantities.Tentative) 
            @Html.Hidden("[" & i & "].Quantities.Actual", currentItem.Quantities.Actual)
            @Html.Hidden("[" & i & "].SKU", currentItem.SKU)
            @Html.Hidden("[" & i & "].OrderID", currentItem.OrderID)

        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Quantities.Actual)
        </td>
        </tr>
    i = i + 1
    Next
```

And the HTML form successfully posts the desired objects (i.e., Model binding seems to work correctly) to the following action signature on my controller

```
<HttpPost()>
Function SaveLines(ByVal Id As Long, postedOrderLines As List(Of OrderLineModel)) As ActionResult
```

Now, I can put my breakpoint into the Validate() method that is called by the default model binder, and can witness the model errors being added and a list of ValidationResult objects being returned.

But, inside the aforementioned controller action, the ModelState.IsValid always returns true. It's as if it got cleared or something. I could post the full controller action, but, it's really not fancy at all.. I can put the breakpoint on the firstline of the action before any logic inside it executes (in other words, directly after model binding has finished and the Validate method has been called) and hovering over ModelState.IsValid shows 'true' when I know there should be errors in the modelstate.

What's going on? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It was user error on my part.. a good one, though!

So, after further investigation, the FORM posts back to a totally different controller class and  action. That one then passes control to the contoller action in my original post. So, that's why my ModelState was getting lost.

Here's the 'actual' controller action that was getting posted to (and it's ModelState was properly invalidated exactly when it was supposed to be) - I had only taken care to pass over controllerContext - which turned out to be insufficient.

```
<HttpPost()>
Function EditLines(ByVal Id As Long, postedLines As List(Of OrderLineModel)) As ActionResult
        Dim lineControl As New LinesController()
        lineControl.ControllerContext = Me.ControllerContext
        Return lineControl.SaveLines(Id, postedLines)
End Function
```

There doesn't seem to be a way (that I know of) to pass over the readonly 'modelstate' property of the invoked controller to a different controller instance. So here's the fix I had to put in place.

```
<HttpPost()>
Function EditLines(ByVal Id As Long, postedLines As List(Of OrderLineModel)) As ActionResult

    If Me.ModelState.IsValid Then
        Dim lineControl As New LinesController()
        lineControl.ControllerContext = Me.ControllerContext
        Return lineControl.SaveLines(Id, postedLines)
    Else
        Return EditLine(Id, postedLines(0).SKU)
    End If
End Function
```

Why do I have two different contoller actions to handle the same form POST?
Its hard to explain other than to say I have two different user experience paths (or two different business scenarios) requiring different contollers, but each utilizing the same view razor.. and since the razor FORM posts back to the controller it came from, I end up having to redirect the posted data to the desired controller in the above manner, in order to keep all the logic in a single place. Maybe not the best design, eh?